# tomcat does not start on linux

Tags: linux, tomcat7

This is what I have done so far

1. Downloaded tomcat 7
2. Installed Java
3. Set JAVA_HOME and CATALINA_HOME

Now I am running the startup.sh and it does nothing but display this

```
bash-4.1$ pwd
/scratch/user/Installs/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin

bash-4.1$ ./startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /scratch/user/Installs/apache-tomcat-7.0.42
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /scratch/user/Installs/apache-tomcat-7.0.42
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /scratch/user/Installs/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /scratch/user/Installs/jdk1.7.0
Using CLASSPATH:       /scratch/user/Installs/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/bootstrap.jar:/scratch/user/Installs/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

What is missing here? Any pointers? All I want to do is install tomcat on this Linux box and deploy a simple application

Comment: There should be a log file in `/scratch/user/Installs/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/logs`, check these if there's something of interest and add that to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue after taking a look at the logs. Apparently, this is all that is displayed when the tomcat is started. I would expect something like "tomcat is running" which is not the case.

Comment: Lesson: always check (with ps, or by browsing to localhost:port) to see whether something actually went wrong, or if the program is just not overly noisy :-)